# Is my joke offensive?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, specific-answer, deleted-answers

My answer to the question [Why is "mathematical induction" called "mathematical"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1080417/why-is-mathematical-induction-called-mathematical/1080427?noredirect=1#comment2198956_1080427) was immediately removed. It is intentionally a joke and that seems to be obvious. The reason of closing I can deduce is that my joke was offensive. Was it?

Comment: I thought it was funny in its way and not offensive at all. But it was not an answer to the question, so I support Pedro's decision. It would have been very much ok as a comment. All: There are a few flagged comments deleted from this thread. The reason for those deletions is not that the mods will willy-nilly protect each other from criticism. I simply reacted to flags coming from users like you. Please give us new mods a bit of time to learn the ropes. We are getting the hang of it ok IMHO :-)

Comment: Can you repeat said joke here so everybody knows what you are talking about?

Comment: I agree. Whether it was offensive or not depends on how funny it is.

Comment: @user132181 As you wish. (Some formatting is lost in this comment.) 
 

"To know, that someone whispered the answer. An authentic example from an exam in Poland:

 >   Zadanie rozwiązujemy metodą indukcji *magnetycznej*

There should be *matematycznej*. The former means *magnetic*, the latter *mathematical*, but the Polish versions sound more similar than the English ones."

Comment: Comments are mathematically probably more mathematically likely to be a better forum for mathematically amusing remarks.

Answer (score 23):

I deleted your answer. I didn't find it offensive. Rather, it was completely irrelevant to the question at hand.

Comment: Thank you! I was afraid that I had done something against the rules.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke You kinda did, you posted something as an answer even though you knew it wasn't an answer... Hence why it was deleted.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi It was an answer, but of very restricted application. However at least once the word "mathematical" near "induction" helped to find a cheater. :-)